# How to use Thumbnailator Position

Tags: java, thumbnails

I'm using Thumbailator and I'd like to know how I could set change watermark's position...

```
Thumbnails.of(background).forceSize(1100, 500).watermark(Positions.CENTER, avatarPlusBorder, 1f).addFilter(filter)
                            .outputFormat("png").toOutputStream(os);
```

How can I change watermark's position to (for example) x = 300, y = 200?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the API for Thumbailtor? Here is the link you need https://coobird.github.io/thumbnailator/javadoc/0.4.8/ for how you can use the position method. At the bottom of the API is watermarks, the constructor for this is as follows:

```
public Watermark(Position position,
                 BufferedImage watermarkImg,
                 float opacity)
```

Hope this helps.